# Kerasを用いたとき計算途中にログを出力させない方法

Tags: python, python3, keras

python3を用いて、GPU上でKeras+Tensorflowを用いて簡単な計算をさせています。

現在、計算途中で、出力を表示させない方法を探しております。

自分の理解では、Kerasは毎回計算結果として以下のような出力を表示します。

```
Epoch 1/500
69/69 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 9828.8662
Epoch 2/500
69/69 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 338466.6562
```

KerasのDocumentを調べた限りでは、Callbackというところでどうやらこの情報のやり取りは行われていますが、その出力を止める方法に関しては、わかりませんでした。

もし誰かご存知の方が追われましたら、ご教授をお願いします。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 関連: ["Show progress bar for each epoch during batchwise training in Keras"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39124676/5989200) -- 本家 Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

たとえば、以下のように、model.fit の verbose を 0 にして出力を抑止できます。

```
model = Sequential([
    Dense(input_dim=2, units=1),
    Activation('sigmoid')
])
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=SGD(lr=0.1))
X = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]])
Y = np.array([[0], [1], [1], [1]])
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=200, batch_size=1, verbose=0)
# verbose: 0 for no logging to stdout, 1 for progress bar logging, 2 for one log line per epoch.
```

Comment: まさしく、同じようなものを書いておりました。fitの中にverbose=0を加えることで回避できるがわかりました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

`.fit()` や `.fit_generator()` のオプション引数で `verbose = 0` とするとログが出力されなくなります。このオプションはデフォルト値が `1` であり、プログレスバーを出力する設定になっています。

たとえば Sequential モデルの [`fit` メソッドのマニュアル](https://keras.io/ja/models/sequential/#fit) には次のように書いてあります。

> **verbose**: 0とすると標準出力にログを出力しません． 1の場合はログをプログレスバーで標準出力，2 の場合はエポックごとに1行のログを出力します．

Comment: keras の関連 issue: ["What should I do if I don't want Keras to display progress bar?"](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/1007)

Comment: ありがとうございます。fitを使っていまして、それの中につけるoptionでしたか。。。不勉強でした。ありがとうございます。